# How to change pptp vpn remote password 12.04

Tags: networking, password, vpn, pptp

I'm looking for a way to change my pptp VPN connection password on the remote server, is there any way to do this? 
I know that from windows if the password expires the connection automatically prompt you to change your remote password, this does not happen in Ubuntu, if the password expire your connection simply fail (and you need to go trough log files in order to understand that your password is expired).
Is there any way to change the remote password before the expiry date?

Comment: PPTP is a pretty old and insecure protocol.  As I understand it, it doesn't have a password change mechanism nor a mechanism for reporting that your password expired.  The only way would be for the remote connection location to email notify you about a password expiration issue if your PPTP is tied to a given logon protocol like Active Directory in Windows which would do as you describe in Windows.